# how to export the filesystem from one container to another

Tags: linux, ssh, docker, docker-compose

I have a container A for running tests against a service running in container B.
container A needs to be able to go through the filesystem of B so it can create / delete files in specific folders, but I can't use volume mounting for sharing these folders (hard requirement).
I tried to install an ssh server on container B, but container B is already running another service as entry point.
I could override the entry point, or use something like supervisord to run multiple services, but I am thinking that there has to be an easier / cleaner way to do it.

Comment: You do this with a shared volume. That means you are going to have to deal with whatever office politics are preventing you from doing your work.

Comment: it's not office politics, it's because I am using circleci docker executor to run this, and it doesn't allow volume mounting. https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007324514-How-can-I-use-Docker-volume-mounting-on-CircleCI-